# Laravel - Listar com relação de tabelas (estado/cidade=>pessoa)

Tags: mysql, laravel, modelo-relacional

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

**contatos** =>
id - nome - estado - cidade

**estados** =>
id - estado - sigla

**cidades** =>
id - cidade - id_estado

---

E os seguintes modelos:

**Estado.php**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Estado extends Model{
    protected $table = 'estados';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function contatos(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contato');
    }
}
```

**Contato.php**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contato extends Model{
    protected $table = 'contatos';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function estados(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Estado');
    }
}
```

---

E para listar:

```
$request = Contato::orderBy($column, $sort)->paginate($paginator);
```

E como faço com que, invés do id de estado, apareça o nome do estado(o mesmo vale pro bairro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, vamos lá. Primeiramente vamos impor algumas dúvidas quanto a sua lógica e se possível algumas correções.

`Contato hasMany Estados`

Em tradução livre esta dizendo que: Contato contém vários Estados.

Esta correto?

Não seria mais concreto: Contato possui uma cidade ou Contato pertence a um estado, pois em questão de integridade da sua aplicação não é possível existir um contato sem informar o estado.

Sendo assim seria relacionamento `hasOne` ou `belongsTo`

Agora vamos ao código.

Cada contato você deverá puxar pelo eloquent seus relacionamentos, ou seja, se vier o contato `Carlos Eduardo` você deverá puxar o estado dele automáticamente.

Para fazer isso existe duas maneiras no Eloquent.

#### Primeira

Ao requisitar a lista de contatos você chamar o relacionamento

```
$request = Contato::orderBy($column, $sort)
           ->with('estados', 'bairro') 
           ->paginate($paginator);
```

Este método tem nome de `Eager Loading Multiple Relationships`. Você pode conferir na documentação.

O que ele faz? Ele diz para o eloquent: Cara, a cada contato que você retornar para mim, você busca o `estado` e pega o `bairro` também do contato, beleza?

### Segundo

Este método você irá definir no model que a cada consulta que ele sofrer ele deverá chamar o relacionamento automáticamente. Essa é diferente do método UM, que você define quando quer chamar o relacionamento. Neste método será em TODAS querys.

Para usar este método basta criar uma `propriedade` no model de contato

```
public $with = ['estado'];
```

Depois de fazer algum desses métodos para recuperar o nome do estado:

```
$request = Contato::orderBy($column, $sort)
           ->with('estados', 'bairro') 
           ->paginate($paginator);
foreach(...);
 {{ $contato->bairro->sigla }}
endforeach;
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, porém está dando o seguinte erro: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'estados.contato_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `estados` where `estados`.`contato_id` in (1, 5, 9, 13, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21))`. Porque ele está tentando buscar 'contato_id' dentro da tabela 'estados'?

Comment: `$this->hasOne('App\Estado', 'local_key', 'fk_key); no model, altere por suas chaves

Comment: Deu certo! Vlw cara. Tenho muito que aprender de laravel ainda.

Comment: @KelvymMiranda marque então a resposta como correta.